# Chrome Extensions & Javasctipy Database

Tags: javascript, database, sqlite, google-chrome

I'm trying to build a Chrome extension that will have a heavy use of data and images.

What are my options when it comes to storing the data?

I'm hoping that I have some kind of SQL option (SQLite).

Comment: It seems like Web SQL is becoming obsolete. Use IndexedDB instead!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could go for [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoded images stored in a [web SQL database](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/). With the help of a canvas in javascript you can easily retrieve and manipulate the image data.

### edit

It seems like Web SQL is becoming obsolete. Use [IndexedDB](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/IndexedDB/raw-file/tip/Overview.html) instead!