# Chrome extension, Store data

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've read this question: [Chrome Extensions & Javasctipy Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089422/chrome-extensions-javasctipy-database) but I want an answer with more details and more clear.

How can I store some of my extension settings?

Is it possible to use a database to do such things with JavaScript?

Is there any good tutorial on it?

I don't want to use Local Storage, because I **do not** want the behavior of SESSIONS

Thanks.

Comment: *"I don't want to use Local Storage, because I do not want the behavior of SESSIONS"* local storage != session storage

Comment: Maybe he means `cache`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could use `chrome.storage.sync` or `chrome.storage.local` ([docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage)). Both are local storage (not session storage); `sync` has the additional advantage that it syncs to the user's Google account if they've connected Chrome to it.

Comment: Will it end after April? like Google+ service.

Comment: @ChanjungKim - No, they're completely unrelated.

Answer (score 3):

The following page lists the storage mechanisms in HTML5. WebSQL gives you a pretty good database for your javascript to use.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage

UPDATE: It has been some time since I posted this. WebSQL has been dropped. Browsers will probably still continue to support it, but all the implementations have been SQLite. IndexedDB is the way to go now.  I have used it and it is a little hard to get into, but works well for a client side database.

UPDATE AGAIN: Chrome changing things. See [T.J. Crowder's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26251407/253298).

Comment: So SQL like implementation will not be supported anymore? I am using WebSQL but somehow I can't even insert data into it via Extension nor it' viewable in INspector: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36324096/chrome-extension-webql-database-is-not-created

Comment: WebSQL was dropped as a proposed standard. I would suggest using IndexedDB. You will find better cross-browser support for it, and it is less likely to be deprecated for Chrome extensions. I don't know of any plans to remove WebSQL from Chrome though, so you may be fine. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/220254/why-is-web-sql-database-deprecated#answer-220257

Comment: Is `IndexedDB` usable for the Chrome extensions now?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a simple solution for you if you just want to save some settings. It also has some examples, hope it helps.

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It would be better to post your examples here rather than using a link, for posterity's sake.  Links can become broken, so better to have a record of it here.